# Jordan measure: half open intervals versus closed intervals.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading the definition of Jordan measure [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Jordan_measure_of_.22simple_sets.22) and I have problems in understanding why the [main definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Jordan_measure_of_.22simple_sets.22) should be given considering $n$-dimensional rectangles given by half-open intervals, while  $n$-dimensional rectangles given by closed intervals are included in the [more complicated extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Extension_to_more_complicated_sets). Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think it's just because it's easier that way.